# Switching ruby version to run a command on server

Tags: ruby, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I have a Ruby application (non-Rails) which I deploy with capistrano. I can ssh into my server, `cd` into the `/current` directory and start it with the command

```
ruby tweet_tracker.rb start
```

However, if I cd up a level and run

```
ruby current/tweet_tracker.rb start
```

I get the error:

```
/home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- tweetstream (LoadError)
    from /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/deploy/dev/tweet_tracker/current/tweet_tracker.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Now this is obviously because I'm running the command using different ruby versions in each directory.

I have a `.ruby-version` file in the application which specifies `ruby-1.9.3-p392`. My capistrano deploy script specifies `set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3-p392'` and when it runs `bundle install` as part of the deploy process, it installs the gems for 193-p392.

Problem is, when I try to start the application from outside the application directory, it uses the default Ruby (set by RVM to be a lesser version of 193).

How do I ensure that the application uses the Ruby version specified by it's `.ruby-version` when run?

I'd rather not change RVM's default Ruby version since there are other applications running on the system.

Comment: You could create a script to cd into the correct folder and start the app?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example project:

```
myproject/
├── .ruby-version
└── subproject/
    ├── .ruby-version
    └── script.rb
```

myproject/.ruby_version:

```
system
```

myproject/subproject/.ruby_version:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

myproject/subproject/script.rb:

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

Now i suppose your problem can be mimicked like this:

```
$ cd myproject
$ ruby subproject/script.rb
1.8.7
$ cd subproject
$ ruby script.rb
1.9.3
```

One way around this is to use the poorly documented command `rvm exec`:

```
$ cd myproject
$ rvm 1.9.3-p392 exec ruby subproject/script.rb
1.9.3
```

Which you could extend to automatically read the `.ruby-version` file:

```
$ rvm `cat subproject/.ruby-version` exec ruby subproject/script.rb
1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

RVM is often quite painful when it comes to writing scripts that call Ruby applications. There exists a better [Ruby version wrapper](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) that many user have migrated to. One of the main problems with RVM that it is well suited for [interactive shells](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html), but not so much for scripts.

The main problem is that RVM sets-up an [`after_cd` hook](https://rvm.io/workflow/hooks/), and that's something you will only get in the interactive shell; as a result, the users are required to run a sequence of commands similar to this:

```
cd $APPDIR
source /home/$APPUSER/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm rvmrc trust && rvm rvmrc load
bundle exec ./bin/server start
```

You can use [`rvm wrapper`](https://rvm.io/integration/init-d/) to generate an init script. Though, for example, it is somewhat more tricky to integrate with [Upstart configuration](http://techhelplist.com/index.php/tech-tutorials/43-linux-adventures/85-upstart-ruby-job-with-rvm).